# Open Vim From PHP CLI

Tags: php, vim

How do you open up vim from a CLI like svn and git do when you drop -m from commit commands?

I'm getting the follow error: Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal

```
`echo "Please edit this file" > file.name`;
`vim file.name`;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP Doesn't automatically pass thru the STDIN/STDOUT streams, you need to do it manually:

```
`echo "Please edit this file" > file.name`;
system("vim file.name > `tty`");
```

(Note: I don't really understand what I'm talking about, I just know the above works.)

Comment: This worked great.  Had some issues with it though, since you were changing the output buffer system returns automatically to the PHP script before you exit vim.  I changed it to exec();  which is the same as ``.  And that prevented the hanging.

Comment: Is it supposed to work on Windows?  I got the warning Logan mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is a example using proc_open in PHP, only runs in systems with /dev/tty (Linux/OSX)

```
<?php

$descriptors = array(
        array('file', '/dev/tty', 'r'),
        array('file', '/dev/tty', 'w'),
        array('file', '/dev/tty', 'w')
);

$process = proc_open('vim', $descriptors, $pipes);
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

I just realized it sounds like you already have this set up for svn/git... what are you trying to open it from?

---

for bash: `export SVN_EDITOR=vim` although `EDITOR` will work as well, though this will influence other things as well. IF for some reason vim isnt on your path youll need to use the full path as well. Place this in your `.profile` or `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Trying to write a php script to open vim in a similar manner.