# Open vim from PHP like git

Tags: php, vim

How do i open vim from a PHP file to edit some other file like git when you run "git commit"  without the -m flag?

I've tried this solution [Open Vim From PHP CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614715/open-vim-)
from-php-cli but it gets me some IO error with vim :

Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a termin?

is there other way to do this? probably with bash or something else?

Comment: That's the second similar question in two days and the same underlying problem: you want to build something that works like `$ git commit` but you don't even look at how it does it.

Comment: @romainl I think what he wants is like the [edit](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Editor-integration#Edit_command) command in pry or [\e](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html) in psql.

Comment: @R0MANARMY, yes, both use the same method as git: they use a temporary file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it using the proc_open method with one of the solutions from [Open Vim From PHP CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614715/open-vim-) and a cycle that constantly checks if the process is still running. Once you finish editing it continues running the script.

```
$descriptors = array(
        array('file', '/dev/tty', 'r'),
        array('file', '/dev/tty', 'w'),
        array('file', '/dev/tty', 'w')
    );        
    $process = proc_open($_SERVER['EDITOR']. $filename, $descriptors, $pipes);
    //if(is_resource($process))
    while(true){
        if (proc_get_status($process)['running']==FALSE){
            break;
        }
    }
```

It's not very elegant but it does the job :)

PS:I'm sorry for the bad English >.<

Comment: Your English was perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Vim is an interactive editor. The error you are getting ("Output is not to a terminal") is a precise description of the problem. You can't control Vim from a PHP script.

If you need to pass text, you should use alternative approaches like the aforementioned `-m` flag or STDIN.

Comment: is there other way to open any terminal editor executing a PHP/bash script to edit some file? the file is not necessary empty...

Comment: you should load the whole file into a string variable in PHP (with `file_get_contents`), edit the string and then save it again.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to execute a bash script with PHP?

Take a look at:

```
shell_exec()
exec()
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.shell-exec.php

http://php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php

The first one will return data from executed command, if you do a `cat file.txt` you will end up with a string which contains the content of file.txt

If you use exec it will not return std output, but will return true/false if the given command was successful.

You can now write a simple bash script which does manipulate text and then execute it via PHP.